# overhead of cabal run

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-criterion

I need to benhmark another project in my program, and right now I'm doing

```
    system $ "cd " ++ projDir ++ "; cabal build"
    let runProj = system $ "cd " ++ projDir ++ "; cabal run > /dev/null"
    (m, _) <- measure (whnfIO runProj) runs
```

with `criterion`. I know `cabal run` will check if the project has been built every time it's called, but other than that does it produce significant overhead? Is there a better way to benchmark other projects within a haskell program?

Comment: I don't have specifics, but I can't imagine that this would be a good way to profile a Haskell program. Why not compile it and then benchmark running it directly?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, only that I'm compiling with cabal because I can specify ghc flags per project.

Comment: I guess the question boils down to "how to benchmark a project within a haskell program". The criterion documentation explains how to benchmark pure function and IO action, so now I'm running the project as an IO aciton

Comment: It wasn't what you were doing when I commented but I see you have changed your example code since.

Comment: This seems like a pretty bad idea, unless it is actually `cabal run` that you want to benchmark. Why not add an executable to the package itself that depends on criterion and benchmarks the actual function you care about? Or at least add enough hooks to the other project that you can write that executable with the other package as a dependency. Down your current path lies madness.

Comment: I will take the advice. But I'm still curious if there's any reason that the criterion library doesn't provide functionalities for benchmarking full projects?